# .htaccess rewrite problems - Remove .php Extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am running a web server locally. I'm using .htaccess in my website root (I know it's not recommended, whatever)

I am trying to rewrite so that the .php extension is removed from page names (eg. domain.com/sub/ shows domain.com/sub.php). I have followed every tutorial on the internet I could find but it is just not working. It seems that I am having problems with the rewrite module in general.
I have activated it and allowed .htaccess, but if I go to domain.com/sub it just shows 404 (which is proof that my .htaccess works, because the 404 page shows). I recently moved to this new server from an external host which it worked on.

I'm running Ubuntu Server 14.04.

If anyone could help it would be appreciated

Edit: Forgot my code, this is what's in my .htaccess right now:

```
RewriteEngine on

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
Options -Indexes

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#To remove www header
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Please show the code you've been using

Comment: What happenes when you go to **/foo.php** (with extension) ?

Comment: Are `sub.php` and .htaccess located right under website root?

Comment: @Anubhava i just realised that the value of %{REQUEST_FILENAME} doestnt contain slash at the end?

Comment: @starkeen: Yes that's right.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @anubhava !

Comment: foo.php would work correctly, but just foo wouldn't

Comment: Still having problems, any fixes?

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser?

Comment: I know for a fact that it works as my 404 and 403 pages are working. They are only mentioned in the .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

I know this method is not from .htaccess but you can remove .php from the url by **setting expose_php to off in your php.ini** file.

please see PHP manual for details:
http://php.net/manual/en/security.hiding.php

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: thanks very much for that info still a kinda a newbie.